# JPA Select List Object with GorupBy Clauzule

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In my database I Have following structure :

```
ID NAME COUNT SOMETHING..   OWNER   DATE
```

And now . I would like to select for each Owner  record with max date.

Without GROUP BY clauzule my  repository looks like :

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    MyEntity findTopByOrderByDateDesc();
}
```

But with Group by it didiny works.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property groupByOwner found for type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grouping support for Spring Data yet, thus it won't work.

In case you want this, you have to write your own query.